# Как в боте Telegram получить сообщение от бота, ничего ему не отправляя?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, sendmessage

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить поставленную проблему.
Я хочу, чтобы при работе кода сообщение от бота отправлялось сразу же, как мы попадаем в функцию "sendp" без нужды отправлять новое сообщение.
**Пример, как это работает:**
Бот: /Отправил картинку/
Бот: Тебе нравится картинка?
Я: да
Бот: Вот и здорово, тогда отправлю её ещё раз!
Я: /записываю любую строку/
Бот: /Отправил картинку/
Бот: Тебе нравится картинка?

**Пример, как мне нужно,чтобы это работало:**
Бот: /Отправил картинку/
Бот: Тебе нравится картинка?
Я: да
Бот: Вот и здорово, тогда отправлю её ещё раз!
Бот: /Отправил картинку/
Бот: Тебе нравится картинка?

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot(' ')



@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])

def sendp(message):
    bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, open("filename.png", 'rb'))
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Тебе нравится картинка?')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, likeit)
    
    
def likeit(message):
    if message.text == 'да':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Вот и здорово, тогда отправлю её ещё раз!')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, sendp)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'А если подумать?')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, likeit)

        
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам не нужно регистрировать обработчик функции sendp, просто вызывайте ее, и передавайте туда текст который должен отображатся под фото.

Вот полный код:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def process_start(message):
    bot.send_message(
        chat_id=message.chat.id,
        text="Привет, я сейчас отправлю тебе картинку",
    )

    send_photo(message, "Тебе нравится эта картинка?")

def send_photo(message, text):
    bot.send_photo( 
        chat_id=message.chat.id, 
        photo=open("filename.png", 'rb'),
        caption=text,
    )
    bot.register_next_step_handler(
        message,
        question,
    )

def question(message):
    if message.text == "Да":
        bot.send_message(
            chat_id=message.chat.id,
            text="Вот и здорово, отправлю ее еще раз",
        )

        send_photo(message, "Тебе нравится эта картинка?")
    else:
        send_photo(message, "А если подумать?")
```

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ!